# How to trigger another controller on AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I don't want to share data between controller. I just want to trigger controller C when i click either tab A or tab B.

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
   <div class="div1" ng-controller="ControllerA" ng-click="changeTab('tab1')">
    ...
   </div>
   <div class="div2" ng-controller="ControllerB" ng-click="changeTab('tab2')">
    ...
   </div>
   <div class="div3" ng-controller="ControllerC">
    ...
   </div>
</body>
```

How this can be done ? Any idea ?

Comment: use `$rootScope.$broadcast`

Comment: can you be more specific about what you want to do? i.e. when tab3 is clicked, hide content in tab1 and content in tab2?

Comment: @grepLines .. there is no tab3 over there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use events, where `$scope.$parent.$broadcast` is a closest path between sibling controllers:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ControllerA', ['$scope', function($scope){
     $scope.changeTab = function(tab){
         $scope.$parent.$broadcast('myevent', tab);
     }
}])
.controller('ControllerC', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.counter = 0;
     $scope.$on('myevent', function(event, tab){
         $scope.tab = tab;
         $scope.counter++;
     });
}])
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="div1" ng-controller="ControllerA" ng-click="changeTab('tab1')">
    Click ControllerA
   </div>
   <div class="div2" ng-controller="ControllerC">
     ControllerB({{tab}}): {{counter}}
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inject `$rootScope` on your controller and on `changeTab()` you can call

`$rootScope.$broadcast('key', true);`

and on the second controller `ControllerC`  listen to that like

```
$scope.$on('key', function(response) {
   //code you want to run here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

$emit is way better that $broadcast : You can call controllers like following code. You can send data as well. Try this .

```
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

            <button ng-click="sendData();"></button>

        </div>


        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
                function sendData($scope) {
                    var arrayData = [1,2,3];
                    $rootScope.$emit('someEvent', arrayData);
                }

            });
            app.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
                $rootScope.$on('someEvent', function(event, data) {
                    console.log(data); 
                }); 
            });
        </script>
```

or the simplest but not recommended way :

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="div1" ng-controller="ControllerA"  ng-show="tab1" ng-click="changeTab('tab1')">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="div2" ng-controller="ControllerB" ng-show="tab2" ng-click="changeTab('tab2')">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="div3" ng-controller="ControllerC">
        ...
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.tab1 = true;
        $rootScope.tab2 = false;
    });

    app.controller('ControllerA', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.changeTab = function (tab) {
            $rootScope.tab1 = true;
            $rootScope.tab2 = false;
        }
    });
    app.controller('ControllerB', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.changeTab = function (tab) {
            $rootScope.tab1 = false;
            $rootScope.tab2 = true;     
        }
    });
    app.controller('ControllerC', function($scope, $rootScope) {

    });
</script>
```

Comment: there is no tab3 over there

Comment: You can't have that variable? is that what you mean?

Comment: no, i don't. i just wrote 2 tabs which are div1 and div2. div3 is different section. it is not a tab.